# javac "no source files" when using -h option

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, header-files

I'm trying to experiment with using the JNI and JDK 9. I have a class `NativeTest.java` that looks like this:

```
public class NativeTest {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }

    private native void sayHello();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NativeTest().sayHello();
    }
}
```

I compile the class, then use `javah NativeTest` to generate the header file.

Upon issuing `javah`, I get this warning:

```
Warning: The javah tool is planned to be removed in the next major
JDK release. The tool has been superseded by the '-h' option added
to javac in JDK 8. Users are recommended to migrate to using the
javac '-h' option; see the javac man page for more information.
```

I know it'll be quite a while before the next major JDK release, but I figured I'd start getting used to this new option now.

So upon trying `javac -h NativeTest.java` (and other variations like `NativeTest`, `NativeTest.class`, etc.) I keep getting this error:

`javac: no source files`

I haven't been able to find any help online, probably because this feature is relatively new, and I can't find anything about this new `-h` option in the man page.

Anyone else try this yet? What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I found it. You need to specify the directory for where to put the header files. `javac -h . NativeTest.java`. I'll leave the question up in case anyone else runs into the same oversight.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.  That will reduce the number of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution I discovered was that I was not specifying the directory where `javac` should place the header files.

Executing `javac -h . NativeTest.java` worked.

Comment: Note this just chucks the generated `.class` files somewhere else, most likely messing up your source tree. (At least with openjdk version 13 javac).

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8, you had to make intermediate step of generating class files to get C headers

Lets say you have following structure

```
recipeNo001
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── c
│   └── recipeNo001_HelloWorld.c
├── java
│   └── recipeNo001
│       └── HelloWorld.java
├── lib
└── target
```

In Java (prior to JDK 9) you had to compile class and use javah with compiled sources

```
> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_11)
> ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac -d target java/recipeNo001/*.java
> ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah -d c -cp target recipeNo001.HelloWorld
# -d c       -> put generated codes inside c directory
# -cp target -> compiled classes are inside target dir
```

In Java 9 you can use `javac -h` with Java source code

```
> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)
> ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac -h c java/recipeNo001/HelloWorld.java
# -h c       -> create header file inside c directory
```

Answer (score 3):

The javah tool has been superseded by the "javac -h" feature . we should be able to just use the normal Java compiler (with the -h flag in Java 8+) to output those files during the Java compilation step.

**Usage:**
-h directory
Specifies where to place generated native header files.

When you specify this option, a native header file is generated for each class that contains native methods or that has one or more constants annotated with the java.lang.annotation.Native annotation. If the class is part of a package, then the compiler puts the native header file in a subdirectory that reflects the package name and creates directories as needed.

javac -h directory name NativeTest.java will solve the problem