# JNI header in cmd prompt

Tags: java-native-interface

I am trying to make an header for JNI
This is the code in java:

package javaapplication2;
public class JavaApplication2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaApplication2 obj=new JavaApplication2();
    obj.print();

    // TODO code application logic here
}

private native void print();
```

}

The cmd prompt command is

> cd C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2
>
> javah -o head.h-jni-classpath../../build/classes javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.java

It shows these errors

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: directories not supported
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.(RegularFileObject.java:70)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.(RegularFileObject.java:64)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(JavacFileManager.java:785)
        at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:463)
        at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:329)
        at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)

Comment: `javah -o head.h-jni-classpath../../build/classes` <-- Why are there no spaces before `-jni` and `-classpath`?

Comment: Bacause when I put spaces it shows    
unknown option: -classpath../../build/classes

Comment: So put a space between `-classpath` and the path, as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) suggests.

Comment: says that the classname is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Note that `javah` is deprecated. With JDK 8 or higher you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625782/192373) `javac -h`. It's also easier:

```
cd C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2\javaapplication2
javac -h .. JavaApplication2.java
```

Comment: How do I add the name of the header in the command?
Like I have used head.h above.

Comment: The header file name will be generated. You can rename the header yourself later.