# JNI : "receipe for target 'HelloJNI.h' failed while using the 'makefile'

Tags: java, c, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm experimenting the use of JNI with Eclipse, using [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) and I fail to use the makefile as explained in the part "2.6 JNI in Eclipse - step 3".

When I right click on the jni folder, selecting "Build targets" => "Build" => and selecting the target HelloJNI.h => Build, I get the following error message :

> 10:19:12 **** Build of configuration Default for project HelloJNI ****
>   make HelloJNI.h 
>   javac -h -classpath ../bin HelloJNI
>   makefile:10: recipe for target 'HelloJNI.h' failed
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, javac -h -classpath ../bin HelloJNI, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
>
> make: *** [HelloJNI.h] Error 2
>
> 10:19:13 Build Finished (took 801ms)

and the last line of the makefile file shown below indicates there is an error (but which one ?)

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

HelloJNI.h : HelloJNI.class
    javac -h -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*
```

I checked that I'm having a "make" file in "C:\MinGW\bin". I haden't so I made a copy of "mingw32-make.exe" and renamed it "make.exe".
I also tried to change the last intruction javac -h (...) to javah (...) but I get the same error.

I suppose the error line

> CreateProcess(NULL, javac -h -classpath ../bin HelloJNI, ...) failed. make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. [The specified file is not found.]

should help me to understand what is wrong but I didn't succeed.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error does not come from `javac` ´- it is caused by `javac` not being in the *PATH* and the `CreateProcess` system call is unable to locate it, and hence the command is not executed. Nothing you change *after* `javac` is going to help there. Possible fixes are e.g.

- adding the path of `javac` to `PATH`...
- calling `javac` with the full path to it:

  ```
  c:/Foo/Bar/JavaSDK/bin/whatever/javac -h -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*
  ```

Comment: Perfect, it works but I still have a question. I'm using the jdk 1.8.0_111 so, I tried to use javac -h but it failed ; I had to use javah. But, doesn't javac -h should already be allowed in that jdk ?

Comment: @Dr_Click answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577196/javac-no-source-files-when-using-h-option)